# Backup postgresql docker image from WAL using wal-e

Tags: postgresql, write-ahead-logging, docker

I have an image which has wal-e installed and working.  It successfully on `backup-push` sends my WAL to the remote drive.

However when I run `backup-fetch`, I get the error

```
wal_e.main   INFO     MSG: starting WAL-E
        DETAIL: The subcommand is "backup-fetch".
        STRUCTURED: time=2017-09-05T07:45:24.721673-00 pid=3839 wal_e.main   ERROR    MSG: attempting to overwrite a live data directory
        DETAIL: Found a postmaster.pid lockfile, and aborting
        HINT: Shut down postgres. If there is a stale lockfile, then remove it after being very sure postgres is not running.
        STRUCTURED: time=2017-09-05T07:45:24.750882-00 pid=3839
```

So I follow the error and shut down with `pg_ctl stop` and I get:

```
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
```

Then I move to another shutdown method `pkill postgres`.

When i do that it seems to work in shutting down postgres, but then kicks me out of the container and runs the restart protocol.

To fix this, I could get rid of the `restart:always` in my compose file, but I don't want to do this as it poses issues down the line for my orchestration integrity.

Any other ideas on how to restore from WAL using wal-e on postgresql docker image?

I aslo tried running

```
docker exec -t postgres_1 pkill postgres; /usr/bin/envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /usr/local/bin/wal-e backup-fetch /var/lib/postgresql/data LATEST
```

Which would in theory stop and then restore in one swoop, but it does what I would expect it to do.  Stop which restarts the container and then returns the expected error:

`-bash: /usr/bin/envdir: No such file or directory`

I still got the same error if I ran `pg_ctl -U postgres stop` or I got `can not find command pg_ctl` when I ran `su postgres` and then `pg_ctl stop`